# Why can't I craft a manual for the Industrial Foregoing mod for Minecraft 1.16.3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Like the title says, I am unable to craft a manual for the Industrial Foregoing mod. I am using Minecraft Java Edition 1.16.3.

The recipe is supposed to be 1 paper and 1 of any wood. I cannot craft it, and in creative mode I cannot find it anywhere.

https://ftb.gamepedia.com/Industrial_Foregoing%27s_Manual

Comment: Isn't the recipe paper and Treated Wood?

Comment: Either way, the FTB wiki is for 1.12.2; it's very likely the recipe has changed